# What is the difference between Skater .NET Obfuscator Free and Paid

Tags: .net, obfuscation

We have used the paid edition of Skater .Net Obfuscator in the past with our 2.0 framework product.  Now that we've upgraded to framework 4.0 our paid edition doesn't work anymore (it is too old).

I am trying to determine what the benefits are to buying the latest paid edition of the product, as there is a free version that has become available since we last purchased.

Also, does anyone know if the obfuscation settings from the framework 2.0 product can be reused with the new edition, or if we will have to redo the settings?

Comment: I don't see why this was closed for "asking for a recommendation". It clearly is not, its asking about diffentiating two versions of a product. Seems like that would have a clear, objective answer.

Answer (score 2):

The differences between different versions of Skater .NET Obfuscator are covered here:
http://www.rustemsoft.com/SkaterDoc/order.htm

As you can see free (Light) edition of the obfuscator offers very limited number of features. For example it doesn't support public member names obfuscation, and thus may not be suitable for you if you require obfuscation of all code blocks.

I suggest you to take the advice of Skater authors and contact them directly. Maybe you could receive some discount during 2.0 => 4.0 upgrade:

> Also if you would like to Upgrade your current Skater license please
>   [contact us](http://rustemsoft.com/support.asp) and we will point you to a right direction.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I like in Skater free version is command-line support. While I use msbuild on TeamCity to build my projects, it works quite well. Since my software is only for a niche market, an extra layer of protection is good enough to make the boss happy :)

Answer (score 1):

We are a small company and have been using the Solo Developer license since 2013. We have researched several other Obfuscation systems, but will definitely stay with Rustemsoft when we need to purchase a larger Team license.  They have been great to work with. They are professional and respond to our technical issues quickly.  In August, we upgraded from an older version (sorry I can't remember which version) but all of our settings came over perfectly.